# How to set QMainWindow as the modal one?

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, qmainwindow, qtembedded

I am using QMainWindow for GUI development of my project..One problem I am Stuck with is blocking all other visible windows from getting input, while one is in operation.

I can not use QDialog.Because rich features of QMainWindow is required.

How can I declare a particular window as modal?

I tried with `QWidget::setWindowMOdality()`.

Here is a demo program, what I tried but it didnt work.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>




int main(int argc, char **argv){


QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QMainWindow *w1 = new QMainWindow();
    w1->resize(500,800);
    w1->move(100,50);
    w1->show();


    QMainWindow *w2= new QMainWindow();
    w2->resize(800,500);
    w2->move(50,50);
    w2->show();

    w2->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);


    return a.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try setting the modal flag first, then show the widget.

```
w2->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
w2->show();
```

Also you could use QWidget and build the toolbar, menu bar and status bar.