# QWindow, how to keep one always on top of another one?

Tags: qt

For two QWindow W1 & W2.
Is there a way to make W2 always on top of W1?
The current method I use is to set W2 always on top by  `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

But it also block the modal dialog when the dialog appear behind the window.
How can I make sure W2 on top of W1 without blocking the modal dialog?

I use QWindow because W2 is a QQuickView, which is not QWidget.

I am working on windows.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use QDialog? That would be the intent of QDialog

Comment: The QDialog is modal, but it is under the window W2, so I cannot click on that modal QDialog...

Comment: Why `QWindow`, not `QWidget`? The last allows window flags like `Qt::Window` and `Qt::Tool`.

Comment: @ilotXXI, I use QWindow because W2 is a QQuickView, which is not QWidget.

Comment: Typically what you do in Windows programming is arrange for W1 to *own* W2. I don't use Qt, so I don't know how to set up an owned window relationship, but it is very simple with the Win32 API: you just specify the handle to the owner window (in your case, W1) when creating the owned window (W2). The [SDK documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows). I'll bet Qt allows you to do something similar when creating the window, or perhaps you can set an owner relationship afterwards with something like a `SetOwner` member function.

Answer (score 1):

```
w2->setTransientParent(w1);
```

If you also want to change `w2`'s appearance and behaviour, use `QWindow::setFlags`.

But it may have side effects. E.g. w2 is closed on w1 close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
```

You may have to first call this, while the window isn't shown yet, and *then* call `show()` on your window, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326549/how-to-set-qmainwindow-as-the-modal-one).